# Insert IF record EXISTS in one table and not EXISTS in other

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

Problem with IF EXISTS

I have two tables

```
create table #Table1 
(
     DateID date,  Shop int, MAC int, Stock int, Transit int 
)

INSERT INTO #Table1  values ('01.01.2014', 1, 2, 2,3)
INSERT INTO #Table1  values ('01.04.2014', 1, 2, 2,3)`

create table #Table2
(
    DateID date,  Shop int, MAC int, OnHand int 
)

INSERT INTO #Table2  values ('01.01.2014', 1, 2, 2)
INSERT INTO #Table2  values ('01.01.2014', 2, 3, 1)
INSERT INTO #Table2  values ('01.01.2014', 3, 1, 4)
INSERT INTO #Table2  values ('01.02.2014', 1, 2, 5)
```

Then I need to do insert into Table 1 if it does not exist in Table 1 DateID,  Shop , MAC, but exists in Table 2

I have this statement

```
DECLARE @Date date =  '01.02.2014'

IF EXISTS (SELECT a.DateID, a.Shop, a.MAC 
           FROM #Table1 a  
           INNER JOIN #Table2 b ON a.Shop = b.Shop  
                                 AND a.MAC = b.MAC 
                                 AND a.DateID = b.DateID  
           WHERE a.DateID = @Date) 
   INSERT INTO #Table1 (DateID, Shop, MAC, Stock)
      select 
          @Date, a.Shop, a.MAC , sum (OnHand)
      from 
          #Table2 a
      where 
          DateID <= @Date
      group by  
          a.Shop, a.MAC 
      order by 
          1 
other IF
else
```

It's working  but  because it has

```
IF  EXISTS
```

it's always true, if I am using

```
IF NOT EXISTS
```

it's always false and this part never execute.

[image]
[image]

Please any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` and set `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`

```
create table #Table1  (
     DateID date,  Shop int, MAC int, Stock int, Transit int  ) 
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_RecvID ON #F_STOCK (DateID,Shop ,MAC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in an sql statement instead of an if statement:

```
insert into #Table1
(DateID, Shop, MAC, Stock)

select  @Date, a.Shop, a.MAC , sum(OnHand)
from  #Table2 a
left join #Table1 b
    ON a.Shop = b.Shop  
    AND a.MAC = b.MAC 
    AND a.DateID = b.DateID  
where b.Shop is null
group by  a.Shop, a.MAC 
order by 1
```

If you need an IF stmt - do something like this:

```
set @RowsToInsert = 0

select @RowsToInsert = count(*)  
  from #Table2 a 
  left join #Table1 b 
  ON a.Shop = b.Shop AND a.MAC = b.MAC AND a.DateID = b.DateID 
where b.Shop is null 

IF @RowsToInsert > 0 ...  you will need to put insert logic here

IF @RowsToInsert = 0 ...  no rows are missing, put update or other logic here
```

Comment: The problem is I have to use IF because I have Update if my first IF statment  not going trought

Comment: You could use the select statement to more accurately test for inserts:
       select @RowsToInsert =  count(*) from  #Table2 a left join #Table1 b
 ON a.Shop = b.Shop  AND a.MAC = b.MAC AND a.DateID = b.DateID  
     where b.Shop is null

Comment: but again as I saed it hase to be IF because if first if faild second IF fired and doing update which is work perfectly, and if second if is not firing ELSE fiering. So here should be IF but i couldnt figured out how to not to load records if they are already in first table

Comment: I changed the answer to include an IF statement example

Comment: It still inserting row duplications each tine if I execute it

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use `EXISTS` then this might work:

```
INSERT INTO #Table1 (DateID, Shop, MAC, Stock)
SELECT  @Date, 
        A.Shop, 
        A.MAC , 
        SUM (OnHand)
FROM    #Table2 A
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   #Table1 B
         WHERE  A.Shop   = B.Shop AND 
                A.MAC    = B.MAC AND 
                A.DateID = B.DateID  
        ) 
        AND
        A.DateID <= @Date
GROUP BY 
        A.Shop, 
        A.MAC
```